# Updating Alalmofire and SwiftyJSON for Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm new in dealing with pods, and now I'm trying to update alamofire to alamofire 3.0 as well as SwiftyJSON to 2.3.0 to get Swift 2.0 support
after going to project directory:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.0'
```

But i get these errors:

```
-bash: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git: No such file or directory
Mes-iMac:MyProject.xcodeproj Me$ platform :ios, '8.0'
-bash: platform: command not found
Mes-iMac:MyProject.xcodeproj Me$ use_frameworks!
-bash: use_frameworks!: command not found
Mes-iMac:MyProject.xcodeproj Me$ 
Mes-iMac:MyProject.xcodeproj Me$ pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
[!] Unknown command: `Alamofire,`

[!] Unknown command: `SwiftyJSON,`
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you were trying to execute your Podfile file as if it were an executable bash file... Don't do this!

Comment: @EricD. what should i do :( ?

Comment: @Maha can you write which command you fire?

Comment: When your Podfile is complete, you have to do "pod install" in the Terminal so that Cocoapods will read the Podfile and install the components in your project. You should read the Cocoapods manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit https://cocoapods.org/ and find your library. Then copy the link like so:

[image]

Use `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'` and `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'` in your Podfile

The `Podfile` will look like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'YourProjectName' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'
end
```

and run **pod install** again

Comment: how can i use them in podfile ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but should i cd to podfile in my project ? or to the project ? I'm really confused?

Comment: cd to your project, then check the folder by press ls. If it, then pod install.